# Can't get ST_Distance_Sphere to work

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to use the `ST_Distance_Sphere` function in PostGIS to work, but it's not behaving.

When I run this SQL command:

```
select id, name, location, ST_Distance_Sphere(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(51.51 -0.12)')) as dist_london from stations order by dist_london;
```

I get this error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function st_distance_sphere(geometry, geometry) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 28
```

In case it's relevant: location is a Geometry field. It contains only points.

I can use `ST_Distance` fine. But as I'm looking at spots very far north, it would be better to use something that outputs meters rather than degrees. What's going on here? Is there a PostGIS extension I need to add?

PostGIS_full_version output:

```
POSTGIS="3.0.0 r17983" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " PROJ="6.2.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.2" WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)"
```

(I'm on Postgres 12.)

Comment: What happens if you specify an SRID of 4326 as the second parameter to ST_GeomFromText?

Comment: Same error, alas.

Comment: The deprecated (since 2.2) signatures are removed in 3.x! Use `ST_DistanceSphere`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The name of the function was changed in PostGIS 2.2 and I was looking at old docs. It is now called `ST_DistanceSphere`, which does work. (Docs: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html)